# Flutter Appcheck (not debug) insufficient permissions

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check

For the past few days now I've been trying to get AppCheck to work properly in Flutter while using `AndroidProvider.playIntegrity` but I keep getting permission errors. With AppCheck Firestore already set to **enforced**, all is fine when I'm using `AndroidProvider.debug` (after plugging in the debug token). It's when I stop using debug that's the problem.

Error message

```
W/Firestore( 5050): (24.4.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users/abc123/foo order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
W/Firestore( 5050): (24.4.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users/abc123 order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

**main.dart**

```dart
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();

// Trying to use AndroidProvider.playIntegrity
await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();

// Works fine in debug
// await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
//   androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug
// );
```

**android/app/build.gradle**

```kotlin
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.foo.bar"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    // Tried enabling this but nothing  really happened
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity'

    // Facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'

    // flutter_local_notifications
    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.4")
}
```

**Firestore rules** (for dev purposes)

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    function isAuth() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    
    function isDev() {
      return isAuth() && request.auth.token.email in [
        'testemail@gmail.com'
      ];
    }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isDev();
    }
  }
}
```

I thought maybe I was missing a few dependencies so in my build.gradle file I tried adding

```js
dependencies {
    ...

    // Tried enabling this but nothing really happened so I commented it out
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity'

    ...
}
```

as it was being added in the [Android instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider#install-sdk) but eventually commented it out since it did nothing.

Then maybe it needed to be an actual release so I created an Alpha release over at Play Console and after getting it approved I downloaded the app and it seems I still can't connect to Firestore.

SHA-256 fingerprints in both Project settings and AppCheck PlayIntegrity taken from debug cert, App signing key (Play Console), and Upload key (Play Console).

**On a side note,** I set my `compileSdkVersion` to 33 and the `targetSdkVersion` to 31. Should they be the same?

Answer (score 0):

I am tripping up on similar problems.

All, some or none of the following might help:

The *deprecated* SafetyNet attestation provider works for me on a real device **not** installed from PlayStore using something like this:

```dart
import 'package:store_checker/store_checker.dart' as sc;

      final debug = false;
      assert(debug = true);
      final appcheck = FirebaseAppCheck.instance;
      final src = await sc.StoreChecker.getSource;
      await appcheck.activate(
        androidProvider: debug
            ? AndroidProvider.debug
            : src == sc.Source.IS_INSTALLED_FROM_PLAY_STORE
                ? AndroidProvider.playIntegrity
                : AndroidProvider.safetyNet,
      );
```

I don't know if this is a significant thing, but in my https://play.google.com/console I also went to the `Setup` > `App Integrity` page (from sidebar) and linked my Firebase project as it was not present.

I have yet to publish a new a new build to see if this fixes anything...

It may be that you have to sign the app with a Play Store certificate to get PlayIntegrity to work. I have not figured that one out at all.

#### Update

My problem was related to linking the Play Store with Firebase

I linked the Firebase project in the Play Store settings for App Integrity but I failed to copy the signing key from the `App Signing` tab to the Firebase App Check settings for Play Integrity registration.

Firebase Console > App Check > Apps - click on Android app and add the key.

Comment: [This yt video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0GNuoCOtaQ&t=300s) is what I followed. Right now I'm still running some more tests. I don't recommend using SafetyNet though because of deprecation.

Comment: I was using SafetyNet for testing a release build but I guess debug provider would work for that too
I watched the video but unless I missed something it didn't cover App Check much